# How can I generate view from controller without having/creating/getting the view.ctp file?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

When the 'posts/index' action is executed the 'views/posts/index.ctp' is called.

In 'views/posts/index.ctp' there is presentation of results.

I don't want to create/have/get that 'views/posts/index.ctp' file.

I want to present the result from the 'posts/index' action, I don't need 'views/posts/index.ctp' file.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the autorender to false:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
//any echo's will be printed as the "view"
echo "My Posts\n";
```

Optionally, you can even omit the layout by using:

```
$this->layout = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want a method to automatically load a view, you can set `$this->autoRender = false` inside that method.

You can also use the [`render()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/980/render) method to render a view whose path does not follow CakePHP conventions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create views you shouldn't be using a Model-View-Controller framework.

Comment: So is it geting like Model-Controller framework ? Note: this is only for one action, not for all actions.

Comment: I see. For some reason I got the idea you just didn't want to have anything to do with creating views. Out of curiosity, what makes this one action different from the others?